# How to run background task in VS Code under Windows?

Tags: windows, npm, visual-studio-code

I have setup some scripts in package.json file, which should be run in background, like

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "babel-watch": "babel client -d _tmp/babel -w",
    "server": "node server.js",
    "background": "start npm run babel-watch && start npm run server"
  }
}
```

I would like to run the `background` task from the VS Code, so I set up `tasks.json` like this (some lines are omitted):

```json
{
  "command": "npm",
  "args": [],
  "isShellCommand": true,
  "showOutput": "always",
  "suppressTaskName": true,
  "tasks": [
    {
      "taskName": "background",
      "args": ["run", "background"]
    }
  ]
}
```

If I run the `npm run background` from Far Manager, 2 new console windows are started and I am returned into Far. However, when I run it in VS Code (using `task background`, 2 new console windows are started, BUT VS code *waits* until the task completes, before it lets me execute another task (an error is displayed: `There is an active running task right now. Terminate it first before executing another task.` (and I am given an option "Terminate running task", which only leads to an error `The launched process doesn't exist anymore. If the task spawned background tasks exiting VS Code might result in orphaned processes.`). It is as though VS Code watches all the started subprocesses, or smth like that.

Is there a way to circumvent this behaviour and make VS Code "forget" about spawned background processes?

Comment: this seems to shed some light on this behaviour, but I cannot figure out what that means for me https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/10237

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One *tricky* way I've discovered is as follows:

```json
{
  "windows": {"command": "powershell"},
  "suppressTaskName": true,
  "tasks": [
    {
      "taskName": "test",
      "args": ["(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell).Run('notepad', 1, $false)"]
    }
  ]
}
```

That will start `notepad.exe` and it'll be completely separated from VS Code instance (e.g. you can start the same task again, and it won't complain).

#### Why does it work?

VS Code uses the standard node.js `child_process` module to control children processes ([see `processes.ts`](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/7e293a48bea56ca3a93aec278492746ec513d83f/src/vs/base/node/processes.ts)), and it'll by default watch child process' pipes' state. The pipes are derived by any `start`'ed process instance, that's how VS Code detects the whole process subtree state (and that's why your `start` trick won't work here).

One of the easiest ways to detach child process completely is to use `WScript.Shell` COM object, that's why I've chosen PowerShell for implementation. The same may be achieved with `cscript` and a small script file, or with small helper program that'll call Win32 API function `CreateProcess` with the `DETACHED_PROCESS` flag.

*Pro Tip™*: Replace `1` with `0` to run the process in a hidden window!

Comment: That's what I call "nailing it down" ! Nice done, @fornever!

Comment: very nice. For full paths to the exe with spaces, you need `\"\"\"<path>\"\"\"` and each backslash needs to be escaped: `.Run(\"\"\"C:\\Program Files\\Foo\\foo.exe\"\"\", 1, $false)`

Comment: Very nice. Can you tell me how to stop the task if needed?

Comment: @AshharHasan unfortunately, I think that it could only be stopped manually using Task Manager or by closing the console window (if it's visible). There're no VSCode facility to stop this task, because VSCode have no idea about it at all. You probably may write some manual script with `taskkill`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't run multiple tasks at the same time right now. That's a limitation.

See [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/15179) to track any developments in this field.

If you read the "Current Limitations" portion, the first explicitly says that we can only run a single task at a time right now.

Comment: although, upon another thought, I have some doubts. I am actually fine with Code not running several tasks simultaneously; I just want to be able to it consider the task finished, as long as it has returned (and I guess executing "`start` application args" should return immediately although the `application args` is still running)

Comment: I don't know how `start` actually works. Maybe ask around on stackoverflow? Logically it should exit, but I don't know. Also if you have any suggestions, feel free to chime in at the GitHub issue.